# Python how to expect a number as an input for a variable you created

Tags: python

```
def get_letter_grade(score):

    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
```

Im expecting the input for "score" to be a number only. To do that would I simply use "score = int"

```
def get_letter_grade(score):<br/>
    score = int
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
```

Comment: It would make more sense just to pass in a number in the first place. Having a function like this doing validation/parsing is having it do too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this:-**

```
def get_letter_grade(score):
 if isinstance(score,int):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_letter_grade(score):
    try:
        val = int(score)
        if val>= 90:
            return "A"
        elif val >= 80:
            return "B" 
    except ValueError:
        return("That's not an int!")

print(get_letter_grade(92))
print(get_letter_grade("test"))
```

Output:

```
A
That's not an int!
```